Hook function not working to prevent from infinite debugger : setInterval(function(){debugger;}, 50);
I want to debug my TamperMonkey script in a website, I found that the proposed setInterval(function(){debugger;}, 50);  to prevent debugger.
So I set a user script in TamperMonkey to hook the setInterval function:
var new_setInterval=setInterval;
window.setInterval=function(a,b){
    if(a.toString().indexOf("debugger")!=-1)
        {
        return null;
    }
    new_setInterval(a,b);
}

when i restart the website, it still stucked on the setInterval function, what's wrong with my code?
(P.S. the website is https://animelon.com/video/*)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When does your user script run?
